# How to use the pandas library to achieve the following functions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The input form is as follows：
[image]

The output form is as follows：
[image]

To count the number of device numbers, I can use df['Device No'].value_counts(), but now I need to put the column "Full name of organization" into the output table. How should I write the program?

My current code is as follows：

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("E:\\input.xlsx")

# print(df)

df2 = df['Device No'].value_counts()

df2.to_excel("E:\\output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please add the code you've written so far. It also makes everyone's life easier if you add sample data as text instead of as pictures.

Comment: Ada, I show my code.

Comment: `df2 = df.groupby(['Full name of organization', 'Device No'])['Device No'].count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) and [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html):

```
 df2 = df.groupby(['Full name of organization', 'Device No'])['DeviceNo'].count()
```

For more infomation see pandas cookbook [groupy: split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine).

Comment: Thanks very much ! It slove my problem.